# How to avoid argument might be null

Tags: android, nullpointerexception

I am getting a warning `Argument amountTarget might be null`. Is there any way to ignore this warning?

```
            if (betid != null) {
            String betnumber = mData.get(i).get("betnumber");
            String amountTarget = mData.get(i).get("amountTarget");
            holder.tx_amount.setText(amountTarget);
            holder.tx_number.setText(betnumber);
            holder.checkBox.setChecked(true);

            //getting warning argument exception on amountTarget
            int x = Integer.parseInt(amountTarget) * amountX - deductAmount; 
            holder.tx_counter.setText(x);
        }
```

Comment: please show what is mData ?

Comment: this is mData `private ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> mData;`

Comment: This is the warning but it may be happen if amountTarget  have null or empty. so before you parse by int apply validation.

Comment: why are you using hashMap inside ArrayList?

Comment: check it for null for example `if(amountTarget != null)`

Comment: If there's a warning you should not ignore that. Here warning about **null** means it can potentially lead to **NullPointerException** on further use of that piece of code without checking **nullability**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

check that amountTarget isn't null by doing one of these:

```
if(amountTarget != null){
 int x = Integer.parseInt(amountTarget) * amountX - deductAmount;
}
```

or initialize the variable to something before using it, for example

```
amountTarget = 0
int x = Integer.parseInt(amountTarget) * amountX - deductAmount;
```

alternatively you could also do something like this

```
if (amountTarget == null){
amountTarget = 0
}
```